# Targeting In and Out Animations on Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm prototyping a web app dealing with lots of views that are off screen until activated by an element currently on screen. Example:

```
<div class='current' data-view='home'>
    <a href='#' data-target='menu'>View Menu</a>
</div>

<div data-view='menu'>
    <a href='#' data-target='home'>Go back home</a>
</div>
```

Right now I've got the jQuery rigged to find the matching value of "data-target" to "data-view". When it finds the match, it toggles the class "current" between the two views.

Anyways! I'm hoping someone could help me figure out a good way to apply my enter and exit animations to the toggled elements. Here's what I tried:

```
$('[data-target]').on('click', function () {

    var parentView =    $(this).parents('[data-view]'),
        currentView =   $('.current');

    function finishedAnimation() {
        currentView.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function() { currentView.removeClass(); });
        };

    if (parentView.data('view', 'home')) {
        targetView.addClass('moveFromTop');
        currentView.addClass('moveToBottom');
        finishedAnimation();
        }

    else if (parentView.data('view', 'menu')) {
        targetView.addClass('moveFromBottom');
        currentView.addClass('moveToTop');
        finishedAnimation();
        }

    $(this).parents('body').find('[data-view=' + $(this).data('target') + ']').addClass('current');

    });
```

It works on the first click, but on the subsequent click to return home it fails to perform the animation correctly.

I've been digging around and switch cases look like a viable option (?). If anyone has guidance on a better approach it would be much appreciated.

Comment: So hang on, you want to animate a view when it is clicked on. At the most basic view, right?

Comment: Sort of! More technically I need the animation to have use cases per situation of the click event. As an example -- If a view has two buttons targeting different views, like: 

Button A may tell the current view to exit right and the new view enter from the left.

Button B may tell the current view to exit to the top and the new view to enter from the bottom.

Comment: In that case I would handle all of the animations with CSS3 and transform's. I haven't got time to write it out right now. But this would give you a huge performance boast. I'll add something tomorrow if nobody else has given a decent answer

Comment: Hey Jamie, all of the animations are done in CSS -- its just the class switching I need.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how your setup works, but I prefer to use an object ( as an interface ) for something like this:

```
 function handleView( view ) {
    views = {
      home : function(){ /* Do stuff with view here */ },
      menu : function(){} 
      }

   views[view]()

}

 $('[data-target]').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault()
    view = $(this).parent().data('view') /* This should return 'view name' */
    handleView( view );

 });
```

Remember that if you're adding a class that has a transition associated with it, you'll need to remove it too.

so `targetView.addClass('moveFromTop');` needs `targetView.removeClass('moveFromTop');` in order to properly toggle.

Comment: It looks odd because I have basically no idea what I'm doing when it comes to to jquery. :) 

What you did looks interesting! I can understand it for the most part, I'm just not familiar with all of the tricks jquery has to offer for more complex stuff.

Comment: Breaking functions up into smaller chunks usually helps me keep everything organized. Try something like the above.